# What is the source of the connecting IP address in an Apache log?

Tags: apache

I'm working on a project to determine from my Apache logs the geographic location of incoming requests.

My question in this context is, which IP address does Apache log - the HTTP request header IP address or the connecting device's IP address acquired from the incoming socket connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's from the socket (TCP/IP layer) connection, not HTTP.

(There's no remote-address HTTP header.)